# Store PATH as a variable in centos 7 script

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-satellite

I want to write a script that allows the user to enter a specific file path to use this variable with the find command

I tried this but it seems that my syntax is not right

```
enter file path : $PATH
find $PATH -size +1M  -exec rm {}\;
```

and what if I want the user also to enter the size should I use 
`find $userpath -size $size -exec rm {}\;` or something else

Comment: Two key points: don't use `PATH` variable because it is a key variable of your environment (ex. use `DIR`), and don't use `-exec rm {}` because it may lead you to blindly delete useful files (ex. use `-ok rm {}`).

Comment: and what if I want the user also to enter the size should I use find $userpath -size $size -exec rm {}\; or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `read`.

```
echo Enter file path:
read userpath
find $userpath -size +1M  -exec rm {}\;
```

Also, for safety you might want to use `rm -i`.

Comment: and what if I want the user also to enter the size  
should I use  
find $userpath -size $size  -exec rm {}\; 
or something else

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I seem to have misread your question. So if you want to read input you can use the Bash builtin `read` (see output of `help read`).

You can use `read` with a custom prompt `-p` and its output automatically goes into a (shell!) variable named `REPLY`, unless you give a different name.

```
read -p "enter file path : "
find "$REPLY" -size +1M  -exec rm {} +
```

NB: I also replaced the `\;` by a `+` which *should* result in less invocations by `find`, but may be less portable.

---

The variable `PATH` has a special meaning and comes prepopulated. You don't say which shell this is, but the ground rules are the same in all of those I am aware of. The `PATH` environment variable is used to locate folders which contain executable files (binaries, scripts ...). These are then executable without giving their full or relative path.

Please check out [this piece of documentation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) to learn more. Quote:

> `$PATH`
>   Path to binaries, usually `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/X11R6/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.
>
> When given a command, the shell automatically does a hash table search
>   on the directories listed in the path for the executable. The path is
>   stored in the environmental variable, `$PATH`, a list of directories,
>   separated by colons. Normally, the system stores the $PATH definition
>   in `/etc/profile` and/or `~/.bashrc` (see Appendix H).
>
> ```
> bash$ echo $PATH
> /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
> ```
>
> `PATH=${PATH}:/opt/bin` appends the `/opt/bin` directory to the current
>   path. In a script, it may be expedient to temporarily add a directory
>   to the path in this way. When the script exits, this restores the
>   original `$PATH` (a child process, such as a script, may not change the
>   environment of the parent process, the shell).
>
> **Note**
>   The current "working directory", `./`, is usually omitted from the
>   `$PATH` as a security measure.

Use `echo "$PATH"` to see the *current* contents of this variable in your running shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
read -i "Enter path" PATH
find $PATH -size +1M -exec rm {}\;
```

But, PATH variable would override your binary search path. Also rm command could be deleted quiet early, unable to delete everything.

I suggest following code:

```
read -i "Enter path" DIR
/bin/find $DIR -size +1M -delete -print
```

**This command will potentially destroy your working environment/OS so use at your own risk!**

Comment: and what if I want the user also to enter the size should I use find $userpath -size $size -exec rm {}\; or something else

Comment: Well, read input another variable then, `read -i "Enter size" size`..